# pork shoulder roast roasting question

Tags: pork

I have 2, 10 lb pork shoulder roasts that need to be roasted in my oven and done by noon. What is my start time? I certainly don't want to cook them as if a 20 lb roast, but don't feel certain that only cooking as a 10 ob roast is sufficient.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Pork shoulders should be cooked low and slow, which is great because it gives you quite a bit of wiggle room. I'd recommend 12  hours at 275 with a lid on each roasting pan. I'd also recommend searing them on high heat before roasting in the oven.

Here's some anecdotal evidence to back me up:http://eggheadforum.com/discussion/1143833/how-long-to-cook-two-10-pound-pork-butt

Answer (score 1):

The biggest factor in cooking time is how much of the food you are cooking is composed of surface area. Assuming there is space between your two roasts in the oven, the time needed to cook both of them simultaneously should be roughly equivalent to the time needed to cook one.

Answer (score 0):

Glaze. cook at 200f for 12 hours. Last hour turn heat up to 375 to brown. Make sure done at bone.  Low & slow is best. but cook below 212. If glazed. 275f he is pan roasting with lid. That would hold in more moisture than my way with a lid.